# Monitoring and reporting cumulative elapsed time to read a Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, timing

I'm using a library called [Screentime](http://screentime.parsnip.io/) to monitor the activity of users.  One way I want to monitor user activity is by seeing how long they keep a popover active to read the text.  The problem is that Screentime cannot monitor the popover on mouseover (only recording it as if it's on the screen at the same).  Performance.now as well as console.time can also monitor the information but will not display an accumulation of time once stopped. Is there a way to use this library to monitor user time on the popover, or should I approach it differently to monitor time spent on a popover?

```
$("[id='DATA']").popover({trigger: "manual", container: 'body', title: "TEST!", content: "TEST!"})

$.screentime({
  fields: [
    { selector: '#orderform',
      name: 'Orderform'
    },
        { selector: "Info1",
      name: 'Popover'
    }
  ],
      reportInterval: 1,
  callback: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    // Logs: { Top: 5, Middle: 3 }
  }
});

        if (x === 'DATA'){ document.getElementsByClassName("popover-content")[0].innerHTML =  "<div id = 'Info1' class='fields'>TEST!</div>";
```